# What is the purpose of the Red Star Power?

Tags: nintendo-wii, super-mario-galaxy

After using the Red Star Power in the "Gate" universe and collection all 100 purple coins, you get a new power star and then there are a few red star power pickups around the observatory.

Is there any reason for this other than another method of travel around the observatory, or are they required to find some secret area?

Comment: Flying is fun! What more do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of one-ups you can only get to by flying. I can't remember exactly where they are but I think one is under the entrance to the gate and the other is above the central spire.

The kids also think that it gives you the opportunity to listen to the best music in the game - that which plays when you're flying.

Comment: That is some pretty kickin' music.